# How to remove vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[image]

I want to remove this white scroll space, but i'm not able to do this.
I can't make the display none because after that it will not scrollable for some users having mouse.

```
"&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
            display: "none",
      },
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Answer (score 2):

For hide scroll  in your page you must add this:

CSS:

```
body{
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

And add js for blcok scroll with mouse :

```
function preventScroll(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
}
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('wheel', preventScroll);
```

Comment: some time user do not have mouse wheel. i have consider that case also

Comment: you mean like keyup and keydown?